# Django: control the output to not include null fields

Tags: django, json, serialization

I have a database table with nullable columns I've created a Django model and view to return all objects as Json.

Is there a way to control the returned output so for example if my model has country, city, address and phone number then the output if all values are not null should be: 
`output = serializers.serialize('json', objects_list, fields=('country','city','address','phone'))` but lets say a record is missing a city than the output should look like this: `output = serializers.serialize('json', objects_list, fields=('country','address','phone'))`

how can I reach this result for each and every field (to be omitted from output if null)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [subclassing a serializer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#advanced-serializer-usage), something like this (untested a)

```
class NullToEmptySerializer(serializers.Serializer):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    # Instantiate the superclass normally
    super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Drop any fields that are null.
    for field in self.fields:
       if field.value is null            
           self.fields.pop(field)
```